# Search multiple files though sub folders VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out how to find multiple files through sub folders, I'm looking for different file names and I think that's why I can't solve it.

"file_name" in the code is the name of the varible, I pull the name of the document from the data base which it's stored in a field without the extension and then when it finds the .docx/doc file it should convert it to pdf.

```
    Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("\\192.168.1.70\sisint\court\
agreements")

        For Each fi In di.GetFiles(file_name, SearchOption.AllDirectories)

            'seleccionamos los archivos con las extensiones de Word
            If fi.Extension.ToUpper = ".DOC" Or fi.Extension.ToUpper = ".DOCX" Then
                ListaArchivos.Add(fi.FullName)
                ListaNombres.Add((fi.Name.Substring(0, fi.Name.Length - fi.Extension.Length)))

            End If

        Next
```

Comment: What type of object is file_name? ie are you searching for multiple files by passing each file name to this snippet of code one at a time, or is file_name a `List(of String)` populated with the names of the files you would like to find. From your question it sounds like both. Please clarify your question.

Comment: You're right, It's a List(of String) populated with the names of the files I would like to find

Comment: OK.Is file_name the full path, and by find it you mean access it programmatically or is file_name the name of the file only, and you are trying to find the full path in a specific directory?

Comment: file_name it's just the name of the file, What I'm trying to do is to find a file in a directory which has many sub folders and if it doesn't find it then it should look for it in another folder

Answer (score -1):

To search a directory with multiple sub directories for a file you can use the following line of code:

```
Dim folders As List(Of String) = New DirectoryInfo("C:\Test").EnumerateFiles("test.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).[Select](Function(d) d.FullName).ToList()
```

Replace "C:\Test" with the directory to search and "test.txt" with the filename to search for. If the same file name is in multiple directories all iles matching that name will be returned.

To find multiple file names, just loop through your list(file_name) replacing "test.txt" with the file. How you save all the output is up to you. You can add everything found to 1 large list and then convert them all to pdf's, or you can convert them as you find them.

Here is an example:

```
Private Function FindFiles() As List(Of String)

    Dim allFilesFound As New List(Of String)

    Dim dirSearch = "C:\Test"

    Dim file_name As New List(Of String) From {"test.txt", "test2.txt"}

    For Each file In file_name
        allFilesFound.AddRange(New DirectoryInfo(dirSearch).EnumerateFiles(file, SearchOption.AllDirectories).[Select](Function(d) d.FullName).ToList())
    Next

    Return allFilesFound

End Function
```

Keep in mind that the more files in file_name and the farther up the Directory tree you start searching from, the longer this will take. If you are dealing with large amounts of files, then consider using recursion so you can find all files in one pass. You can take a look here [Recursively search folder with subdirectories in .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303974) and modify the code demonstrated there to fit your search pattern.